# Is there a way of getting the requesting page's title from the request in ASP.NET Web Forms?

Tags: html, asp.net, webforms

In a user control, I need to get the page's title (as in the title element content in HTML, what is displayed as the browser page title).

When I get `Page.Title`, it is empty even though it is set programatically in the Load method of the page itself. Is there any other way of getting the current page's title, maybe from the `HttpRequest`?

Comment: What about `Page.Header.Title` ?

Comment: Yep, that did it, thanks! Post an answer and I'll accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Page.Header.Title` instead.

I believe (haven't confirmed tho) it's because by default `title` element doesn't have a `runat="server"` attribute, while `head` does.